# Identify me through my hobbies

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Rule: I will be posting one hobby per day (in no particular order)(was that a hint?) until the riddle is found.

The riddle's answer is the name of either the real human or their persona.

> 1. I like to virtually explore earth until lost

Comment: Me, when I use Google Earth

Comment: [This meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5374/is-this-considered-a-semi-interactive-puzzle) (and [this one](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/proposal-for-an-an-interactive-puzzle-or-type-of-puzzle-on-topic)) suggests this may not end up being too well received here, George - sorry!

Comment: I initially VTC'ed this question for being unsolvable, but then I solved it. Retracting my close vote (and handing out an upvote, because the puzzle was fun for me.)

Comment: I've downvoted because the incremental update format is antithetical to the purpose of this site; puzzles should be intended to be solvable at any point in their posting.

Comment: Thank you for the info guys, although I've been some time around puzzling I haven't noticed something like that on comments,posts, or the meta. Will make sure to post accordingly.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis thank _you_ for taking the time to learn from this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What an ah-ha moment! Your person is obviously

> Randall Munroe, aka XKCD

Because

> https://xkcd.com/1169/

A list of all of this person's hobbies may be found here:

> https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Category:My_Hobby

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Andy off of [Andy's Safari Adventures](https://www.bbc.co.uk/cbeebies/shows/andys-safari-adventures)?
>  It is a children's TV show where Andy goes on adventures around the world, but is very clearly all green-screened/virtual to the adult eye. He often gets into sticky situations or gets lost (aka fun for the kids to watch).